# Does CWM backup everything? Or just the actual system?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-moto-g, nandroid

I have just created a backup using CWM. A 3.2G backup of a clean factory reset. Mental.

I am wondering that once I have installed all the apps, and make a new backup....that backup will contain EVERYTHING? Apps, photos, music...and so on?

Comment: I've just added the `nandroid` tag to your question – as that's what you're asking about. Please see [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info) for more details – including the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backup created via recovery is a nandroid backup.

Yes, the nandroid backup created by any recovery (CWM, TWRP) will be exact replica of the phone state when the backup was taken- that means it'll have all the files/ data that you have on the phone.

Here is [a good article about nandroid backups](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-a-nandroid-backup-and-how-exactly-does-it-work/)

Comment: Basically correct. Should be worth pointing out *Nandroid* creates complete disk images – so it basically "mirrors" all (relevant) partitions. It's not a file-based (logical) backup, but a "disk-based" one. So naturally, everything on the "disks" is backed up – not only the files, but also where exactly they were stored (not just in terms of directory-structure, but rawly, even which "sectors" they were occupying).